# reference count(*) as total in hive and use total later in same select statement

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to reference count(*) , save it as total and reference it later but it is not working

for eg :

```
  select ((count(*) as total)-count(a)),
  (total - count(b)),
   (total - count(c))
    from table;
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (count(*) - count(a)) AS Column1
      ,(count(*) - count(b)) AS Column2
      ,(count(*) - count(c)) AS Column3
from table;
```

Comment: I just want to do count(*) once and store it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong?  SQL does not allow you to use column aliases in the same `select` statement.  This is to prevent ambiguity caused by things like:

```
select a as b, b as a, b - c
```

What does the third `b` refer to?  The standard is clear:  it refers to the column in the table.

Also, you cannot define column aliases in the middle of the expression.  These are the names of columns in the result set, not variables.

You can fix this by replacing the word `total` with the expression `count(*)`:

```
  select (count(*) - count(a)),
         (count(*) - count(b)),
         (count(*) - count(c))
  from table;
```

I think you can do this in hive just as you would in any other SQL dialect by using a subquery:

```
select (const.total - count(a)),
       (const.total - count(b)),
       (const.total - count(c))
from table cross join
     (select count(*) as total from table) const
```

Comment: This doesn't work in hive. I want to store count(*) somewhere and not calculate it again and again